# How to fix ' ImportError: cannot import name 'string_types' from 'sqlalchemy.util.compat'?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am using Python to connect to Snowflake database to run sql query but encountered this error.
It is a new error as I can run the code without issue previously.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util\deprecations.py", line 281, in warned
    return fn(*args, **kwargs)  # type: ignore[no-any-return]
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    File "C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\create.py", line 552, in create_engine
    entrypoint = u._get_entrypoint()
    
File "C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\url.py", line 754, in _get_entrypoint
    cls = registry.load(name)
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    File "C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util\langhelpers.py", line 372, in load
    return impl.load()
           ^^^^^^^^^^^
    File "xxx\monitoring\envs\Lib\site-packages\importlib_metadata\__init__.py", line 210, in load
    module = import_module(match.group('module'))
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    File "xxx\monitoring\envs\Lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1204, in _gcd_import
    File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1176, in _find_and_load
    File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1147, in _find_and_load_unlocked
    File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 690, in _load_unlocked
    File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 940, in exec_module
    File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
    File "xxx\monitoring\envs\Lib\site-packages\snowflake\sqlalchemy\__init__.py", line 30, in <module>
    from . import base, snowdialect
    File "xxx\monitoring\envs\Lib\site-packages\snowflake\sqlalchemy\base.py", line 13, in <module>
    from sqlalchemy.util.compat import string_types
    ImportError: cannot import name 'string_types' from 'sqlalchemy.util.compat' 
    (C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util\compat.py)
```

Package Version:

1. snowflake-connector-python         3.0.2
2. snowflake-sqlalchemy               1.4.7
3. SQLAlchemy                         1.4.50
4. python                             3.11.4

I have tried to uninstall and reinstall those packages but does not help.

Comment: Please post the full error message, so we don't have to guess where the error happened.

Comment: Thanks and I have edited the error message.

Comment: Can you post a sample of code that you are running and triggers this error?

Answer (score 0):

In my case reinstalling the library worked:

`pip install --upgrade snowflake-sqlalchemy`

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/developer-guide/python-connector/sqlalchemy#prerequisites